# What's wrong with foreign keys?

Tags: database, database-design, foreign-keys, referential-integrity, data-integrity

I remember hearing [Joel Spolsky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joel_Spolsky) mention in [podcast 014](https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W4) that he'd barely ever used a foreign key (if I remember correctly). However, to me they seem pretty vital to avoid duplication and subsequent data integrity problems throughout your database.

Do people have some solid reasons as to why (to avoid a discussion in lines with Stack Overflow principles)?

["I've yet to have a reason to create a foreign key, so this might be my first reason to actually set up one."](https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W13086)

Comment: I am particularly very interested in seeing an actual database implementation without foreign keys.

Comment: Could you point out exactly where he said this, so we can get some context?  The podcasts transcripts are available here
https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W4

Comment: FogBugz has foriegn keys (sort of), they just don't actually make them formally linked in the database.  If you look at the schema you can see FK fields with names that map to PK fields in other tables.  It's all just enforced by code.  Worries the heck out of me, but it seems to work Ok.

Comment: This is a duplicate of: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18717/are-foreign-keys-really-necessary-in-a-database-design#18730](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18717/are-foreign-keys-really-necessary-in-a-database-design#18730)

Comment: I don't think Joel doesn't use FKs, it's just that he doesn't make the database enforce them. Logically, they are still FKs!

Comment: @Daren: See above quote, he pretty much says he doesn't at least!!

Comment: He says he doesn't use foreign keys, but I agree with Daren that what he means is he doesn't use foreign key CONSTRAINTS.  A column in one table whose values are supposed to be taken from the primary/unique key of another table ARE foreign keys, whether you add the constraint or not.

Comment: ...Generally it is foolish not to add the constraint: it ENSURES integrity at all times, even if there is a bug in the application code or if your are working behind the scenes doing a data "fix".

Comment: @TonyAndrews: By that reasoning you wouldn't need to set up a PRIMARY KEY either, as long as your application code will make sure that all records are unique. Sorry, but that's just rubbish. Constraints let the database keep it's data consistent *all by itself*, so why you wouldn't want to make use of that is beyond me.

Comment: @DanMan, don't know where you gained the impression I think that. I actually say above "Generally it is foolish not to add the constraint: it ENSURES integrity at all times"

Comment: I was referring to the comment above that. If you don't *define* it as a FKC, then it really isn't from the DB's POV. (Those are an awful lot of acronyms). Just saying.

Comment: Plenty of people create foreign keys, but just don't declare them.  I wonder if that is what Joel Spolsky means.

Comment: A foreign key IS a constraint. Interpreting some column as the a reference to the primary key of some table by itself does not constitute a foreign key, just like interpreting a numeric column as a counter does not make it a sequence.

Comment: A foreign key constraint is a constraint.  A foreign key is simply a copy of the key data in  some other location, used as a reference by key to the original tuple.  The reference is usually to a primary key.  You would have foreign keys in your relational data model, even if they are not declared as such in the final implementation.

Comment: Duplicate of [Are foreign keys really necessary in a database design?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18717/are-foreign-keys-really-necessary-in-a-database-design)

Answer (score 388):

Reasons to use Foreign Keys:

- you won't get Orphaned Rows
- you can get nice "on delete cascade" behavior, automatically cleaning up tables
- knowing about the relationships between tables in the database helps the Optimizer plan your queries for most efficient execution, since it is able to get better estimates on join cardinality.
- FKs give a pretty big hint on what statistics are most important to collect on the database, which in turn leads to better performance
- they enable all kinds of auto-generated support -- ORMs can generate themselves, visualization tools will be able to create nice schema layouts for you, etc.
- someone new to the project will get into the flow of things faster since otherwise implicit relationships are explicitly documented

Reasons not to use Foreign Keys:

- you are making the DB work extra on every [CRUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) operation because it has to check FK consistency. This can be a big cost if you have a lot of churn
- by enforcing relationships, FKs specify an order in which you have to add/delete things, which can lead to refusal by the DB to do what you want.  (Granted, in such cases, what you are trying to do is create an Orphaned Row, and that's not usually a good thing).  This is especially painful when you are doing large batch updates, and you load up one table before another, with the second table creating consistent state (but should you be doing that sort of thing if there is a possibility that the second load fails and your database is now inconsistent?).
- sometimes you know beforehand your data is going to be dirty, you accept that, and you want the DB to accept it
- you are just being lazy :-)

I think (I am not certain!) that most established databases provide a way to specify a foreign key that is not enforced, and is simply a bit of metadata.  Since non-enforcement wipes out every reason not to use FKs, you should probably go that route if any of the reasons in the second section apply.

Comment: Good list! The DBMs won't check consistency for "R" part of CRUD, so I'd take that part out. Also, it's probably a wash because in your app you do the same thing the DBMS does: you'll check and make sure the parent ID is valid before CRD and that is actually slower than having the DBMs do it!

Comment: Good point, Matt, but as far as doing the same thing the DB is doing in your app -- you probably shouldn't if you have the DB doing it.  Either you trust the DB and use it properly, or it quickly devolves in a key-value store.  If you need key-value stores, there are better options :-).

Comment: What if someone deletes the parent while you're inserting children? Right now when I submit "add comment" -- if you have already deleted your answer, this comment is now an orphan. FKs would've prevented it. Also, I could just change the parentID to be anything I want. Someone needs to check. :)

Comment: Precisely -- it should be the DB's job, since it's the only one that can guarantee transactionality in the face of multiple concurrent clients.

Comment: Oh I thought you were arguing that NO ONE needed to check, I misread your comment!! You are right :)

Comment: Watch out for those "on delete cascade" situations - it can run slow on large databases

Comment: Well thought-out answer!  I was wondering - what's a better Key-Value store for 500M records that can be accessed by concurrent users than a database?

Comment: David B -- check out BerkeleyDB (still free, but now owned by Oracle)

Comment: +1 Excellent answer -- the second reason not to use FK constraints could be thought of "makes it harder to break consistency" which actually sounds like a *good* thing!

Comment: Another reason in favor of foreign keys is that in most RDBMS implementations, declaring a foreign key implicitly creates an index on column(s) that would be most likely to benefit from an index.

Comment: The database for OLTP systems is the method of persisting application data. The only reason databases exist is because application data works with volatile memory. If your distributed cache, for example,  was operating in fast non-volatile memory, which is becoming an economic reality, or was operating in RAM backed to HD by UPS on failure, then no database would be needed. Object modelling, and therefore the diff between aggregagtion and composition (and therefore deletion cascading) should be entirely up to the app logic, and moved to db only for performance or design optimisation reasons.

Comment: Checking the FK consistency is very often a very fast operation, as it's an index lookup. This is valid even in cases where you have lots of "churn", as in those situations, one's likely to have the indexes in memory.
The cases where FK checks can have a noticeable impact is on large batch inserts; in fact, major databases offer options to batch the FK checking as well.

Comment: You have a massive dataset within the table, and it's in a live system that can't go down, and making changes to the schema would lock the table for too long. So you copy the data to a new table, change the schema there, then do an atomic table rename instead (original_table -> original_table_old, new_table -> original_table). FKs make this whole process a lot harder (because the FKs from subtables move during the rename to reference the original_table_old), you have to drop and recreate them, and that takes time itself during which you can get orphaned data.

Comment: Or at least that's the excuse people tell me why their tables don't have FKs to directly related subtables, and why they have tasks to clean up said subtables all the time.

Comment: Thank you @JeeBee for bringing this up. Nobody has addressed restoring backups, moving databases, replication, schema mods on a live database, mass reload of some tables, and other mundane 5mn things that FKs turn into a day long ordeal or even require you to write code.. Nevermind a disaster recovery scenario.. The F in FK becomes another word.. Nobody is reckless with data.. a degree of freedom is matched by an increased risk. That's all. Consistency burden is moved to the app layer.

Comment: I don't like FK. For the backup and freedom that is mentioned in other comments, but for many other reasons. My number one reason, is that I use it for restorative purposes. Like say I have several tables that deal with clients (by an id of sorts). If I delete the record from the main client table, it effective removes all access to that clients records (app doesn't know it exists) this allows me to very EASILY restore a mistake by recreating the single record (rather than hundreds). I have background processes that will remove the data eventually (and backup).  I prefer an API layer over app

Comment: The benefits of using foreign keys FAR outweighs any benefits of not using them in my opinion.

Comment: i find it much easier to setup test without foreign keys.

Comment: The only thing to watch is on large systems like we use, we NEVER configure cascading deletes. Our deletes are done through maintenance scripts that remove children before parents. It does take a little more time to create the batch tasks, but it is worth it for the integrity of the database. I always use FK for optimization and data integrity checks. But the batch removal / maintenance issues do come up with our DBA at times because it can cause an inconvenience for them.

Comment: @Sentinel Your kind of thinking works great when the relationship between data and application is 1:1. In many organizations, a database is central and applications emanate from it like spokes on a wheel. These applications are often written in different languages using different technologies, as time goes on. "Central" databases very often far outlast the applications that access them.

Comment: I'd say 99% of the time, foreign keys make sense. But I have some data that I don't really care that much about, but there's a lot of it (tiny chunks). I want CRUD to be really fast with as close to zero chance of failure. I don't care about orphaned records because the data has a shelf life and eventually gets destroyed. I don't use FKs on this table. There's not benefit to.

Comment: Here we are ten years later. The reason not to use FK's seem to be winning. At every company I go to, they are prohibited.

Comment: Another negative against FK's, perhaps MySQL specific: it makes it hard to run online schema changes, that copy data to a "shadow table" and then swap the new table for the old.

Comment: "I think (I am not certain!) that most established databases provide a way to specify a foreign key that is not enforced, and is simply a bit of metadata."

Does anyone know how to do this in postgres? A couple searches later and I don't have a clear answer other than deleting triggers per table.

Comment: if using soft deletes, 'cascading delete' is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 88):

This is an issue of upbringing.  If somewhere in your educational or professional career you spent time feeding and caring for databases (or worked closely with talented folks who did), then the fundamental tenets of entities and relationships are well-ingrained in your thought process.  Among those rudiments is how/when/why to specify keys in your database (primary, foreign and perhaps alternate).  It's second nature.

If, however, you've not had such a thorough or positive experience in your past with RDBMS-related endeavors, then you've likely not been exposed to such information.  Or perhaps your past includes immersion in an environment that was vociferously anti-database (e.g., "those DBAs are idiots - we few, we chosen few java/c# code slingers will save the day"), in which case you might be vehemently opposed to the arcane babblings of some dweeb telling you that FKs (and the constraints they can imply) really are important if you'd just listen.

Most everyone was taught when they were kids that brushing your teeth was important.  Can you get by without it?  Sure, but somewhere down the line you'll have less teeth available than you could have if you had brushed after every meal.  If moms and dads were responsible enough to cover database design as well as oral hygiene, we wouldn't be having this conversation. :-)

Comment: I'm going to use the distilled "foreign keys are like brushing your teeth: go ahead, do without it, but careful when you smile"

Comment: I personally find that the principles of RDBMS' are much simpler and much more well defined than those of oral hygiene

Comment: 10 years in future, I'm sure going to have this database design talk with my son/daughter so he/she don't mess up and end up being reason for next wall street crash because of a database issue.

Answer (score 55):

I'm sure there are plenty of applications where you can get away with it, but it's not the best idea.  You can't always count on your application to properly manage your database, and frankly managing the database should not be of very much concern to your application.

If you are using a **relational** database then it seems you ought to have some **relationships** defined in it.  Unfortunately this attitude (you don't need foreign keys) seems to be embraced by a lot of application developers who would rather not be bothered with silly things like data integrity (but need to because their companies don't have dedicated database developers).  Usually in databases put together by these types you are lucky just to have primary keys ;)

Comment: I really don't get people who don't have FKs in their database. The last time I worked with someone who didn't have it, he said "no, we enforce that in the application." Except I did a survey of all the customer databases and found most of them did have orphans...

Comment: That usually seems to be the case.  I think you could get away with enforcing ONLY in the database (as long as your users don't mind runtime exceptions) but to have both is really the only way to go.

Comment: Its all in the transcripts / Atwood's response "Atwood: ...based on the foreign keys that you set in the indexes, they figure it out ...

Spolsky: [laughs] Assuming that you do that.

Atwood: Well, assuming that you set your database up properly..."

Comment: Database are not called _relational_ because of the _relationships_ between tables (EVERY kind of database has some kind of relationships between entities!), but because tables themselves are _relations_, in math terms. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database#Relations_or_tables).

Comment: I think what most people dont really understand is that often you build applications that do not perform DELETE. Your data simply gets "nullified" by some flag. Those applications have their own ways of dealing with what to do on DELETE, key is there for implicit reference only and performance is also a component in such situations. Handwaving this as bad design is acting silly.

Answer (score 42):

Foreign keys are **essential** to any relational database model.

Comment: The model, yes. The implemention, not essential, just probably useful.

Comment: Sorry, but the main reason why app developers don't use object database management systems (aka NoSQL databases!) more widely is because of the investment in RDBMSs. Most of the time the database (not the database management system) is a mid-tier object model often involving distributed caches. This is where deletion cascading, ownership and synchronisation of changes has to happen anyway. The RDBMS is used primarily for persistence of this object model, and usually after a painstaking and practically worthless ORM exercise. Relation models are most of the time not necessary!

Comment: no, foreign keys are not compulsary to indicate 
"relational"

Comment: This doesn't really explain much.

Answer (score 30):

I always use them, but then I make databases for financial systems.  The database is the critical part of the application.  If the data in a financial database isn't totally accurate then it really doesn't matter how much effort you put into your code/front-end design.  You're just wasting your time.

There's also the fact that multiple systems generally need to interface directly with the database - from other systems that just read data out (Crystal Reports) to systems that insert data (not necessarily using an API I've designed; it may be written by a dull-witted manager who has just discovered VBScript and has the SA password for the SQL box).  If the database isn't as idiot-proof as it can possibly be, well - bye bye database.

If your data is important, then yes, use foreign keys, create a suite of stored procedures to interact with the data, and make the toughest DB you can.  If your data isn't important, why are you making a database to begin with?

Comment: Nice insight. I would argue that the data is this important for every application that actually gets used. The only thing that differs is the consequences of corrupt data. They are high for  your kind of app...

Answer (score 23):

**Update**: I always use foreign keys now. My answer to the objection "they complicated testing" is "write your unit tests so they don't need the database at all. Any tests that use the database should use it properly, and that includes foreign keys. If the setup is painful, find a less painful way to do the setup."

---

## Foreign keys complicate automated testing

Suppose you're using foreign keys. You're writing an automated test that says "when I update a financial account, it should save a record of the transaction." In this test, you're only concerned with two tables: `accounts` and `transactions`.

However, `accounts` has a foreign key to `contracts`, and `contracts` has a fk to `clients`, and `clients` has a fk to `cities`, and `cities` has a fk to `states`.

**Now the database will not allow you to run your test without setting up data in four tables that aren't related to your test**.

There are at least two possible perspectives on this:

- "That's a good thing: your test should be realistic, and those data constraints will exist in production."
- "That's a bad thing: you should be able to unit test pieces of the system without involving other pieces. You can add integration tests for the system as a whole."

It may also be possible to temporarily turn off foreign key checks while running tests. MySQL, at least, [supports this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_foreign_key_checks).

Comment: I find myself usually going for the middle path here: I use FKs, then I write unit-test helper methods that set up the DB to support various testing scenarios, e.g. a helper method to populate "cities" and "states" for any tests that need those tables populated.

Comment: You should have used link tables between the non-related entities perhaps. Or go further - separate DBS: consider the situation in a Service Oriented Architecture, or Microservice, where each element (clients, accounts, transactions) are different systems, with different DBs. No FKs between them as all. In this case, FKs should be used to prevent orphaned data in subtables for each type of data.

Comment: There are also DBMS that allow to constraints to *deferred* so that they are only checked when you commit the whole transaction, so the order of insert, update, delete doesn't matter

Comment: If you are testing an update from a business layer, your development environment should have the FK present. When you update your record, you should have the columns values you need for the update to succeed. Otherwise, IMHO your test is not valid.

Comment: Your database shouldn't even be involved in your unit tests, you should mock them. On integration testing they would be involved but any problems there due to foreign keys is something your users also will run into unlesss you fix it.

Answer (score 17):

"They can make deleting records more cumbersome - you can't delete the "master" record where there are records in other tables where foreign keys would violate that constraint."

It's important to remember that the SQL standard defines actions that are taken when a foreign key is deleted or updated.
The ones I know of are:

- `ON DELETE RESTRICT` - Prevents any rows in the other table that have keys in this column from being deleted.  This is what Ken Ray described above.
- `ON DELETE CASCADE` - If a row in the other table is deleted, delete any rows in this table that reference it.
- `ON DELETE SET DEFAULT` - If a row in the other table is deleted, set any foreign keys referencing it to the column's default.
- `ON DELETE SET NULL` - If a row in the other table is deleted, set any foreign keys referencing it in this table to null.
- `ON DELETE NO ACTION` - This foreign key only marks that it is a foreign key; namely for use in OR mappers.

These same actions also apply to `ON UPDATE`.

The default seems to depend on which [sql](/questions/tagged/sql) server you're using.

Answer (score 14):

@imphasing - this is exactly the kind of mindset that causes maintenance nightmares.

Why oh why would you ignore declarative referential integrity, where the data can be **guaranteed** to be at least consistent, in favour of so called "software enforcement" which is a weak preventative measure at best.

Comment: Because the developers involved have never tackled a problem that demands a non-trivial, normalized, relational model. Many problems don't, especially the sort that abound in web/"social media" type programming that is all the craze today. If whatever dribbles out the back end of an ORM framework satisfies the problem in alpha, it is unlikely for anyone to think much more about data modeling. Many such problems are just as easily handled by K/V stores, document databases or straight object serialization.

Answer (score 12):

There's one good reason not to use them:    **If you don't understand their role or how to use them.**

In the wrong situations, foreign key constraints can lead to waterfall replication of accidents. If somebody removes the wrong record, undoing it can become a mammoth task.

Also, conversely, when you need to remove something, if poorly designed, constraints can cause all sorts of locks that prevent you.

Comment: Deleting a row in production without backup is not a valid argument. If you don't understand them, you should consider learning about it instead of omitting it.

Comment: @Guillaume I think his answer was a bit sarcastic, not to be taken literally: if you don't understand them, then don't use them. But of course you *should* both understand and use them.

Comment: ^ This. They are useful tools, but in the hands of a novice, they are dangerous tools.

Answer (score 10):

There are no **good** reasons *not* to use them... unless orphaned rows aren't a big deal to you I guess.

Comment: Why are orphaned rows a big deal?

Comment: What about multithreading? They can cause a multithreading nightmare in certain situations. In a complex application with multiple threads writing the database that may be encountering objects which need to reference each other, it is better to control referential integrity in the business logic---particularly if the tables are going to go static afterwards.

Comment: I agree. Also, I prefer to have ophan rows which I can recover later in time, than to have them discarded mercilessly.

Answer (score 9):

"Before adding a record, check that a corresponding record exists in another table"  is business logic.

Here are some reasons you don't want this in the database:

1. If the business rules change, you have to change the database. The database will need to recreate the index in a lot of cases and this is slow on large tables. (Changing rules include: allow guests to post messages or allow users to delete their account despite having posted comments, etc).
2. Changing the database is not as easy as deploying a software fix by pushing the changes to the production repository. We want to avoid changing the database structure as much as possible. The more business logic there is in the database the more you increase the chances of needing to change the databae (and triggering re-indexing).
3. TDD. In unit tests you can substitute the database for mocks and test the functionality. If you have any business logic in your database, you are not doing complete tests and would need to either test with the database or replicate the business logic in code for testing purposes, duplicating the logic and increasing the likelyhood of the logic not working in the same way.
4. Reusing your logic with different data sources. If there is no logic in the database, my application can create objects from records from the database, create them from a web service, a json file or any other source. I just need to swap out the data mapper implementation and can use all my business logic with any source. If there is logic in the database, this isn't possible and you have to implement the logic at the data mapper layer or in the business logic. Either way, you need those checks in your code. If there's no logic in the database I can deploy the application in different locations using different database or flat-file implementations.

Answer (score 7):

From my experience its always better to avoid using FKs in Database Critical Applications. I would not disagree with guys here who say FKs is a good practice but its not practical where the database is huge and has huge CRUD operations/sec. I can share without naming ... one of the biggest investment bank of doesn't have a single FK in databases. These constrains are handled by programmers while creating applications involving DB. The basic reason is when ever a new CRUD is done it has to effect multiple tables and verify for each inserts/updates, though this won't be a big issue for queries affecting single rows but it does create a huge latency when you deal with batch processing which any big bank has to do as daily tasks.

Its better to avoid FKs but its risk has to be handled by programmers.

Comment: I don't think development practices at large banks set the golden standard.

Comment: Absolutely. Automatic operations are always risky, even when you know exactly (not many do) what's happening in the background. Foreign keys are like a safety net, but they carry a non-neglectable overhead and they don't give as much in return. Databases have to be in (technically) an "inconsistent state" every now and then, temporarily, e.g. when maintenance processes are running. The intermittent layer between application and db should be able to handle this. It's not a good practice to restrict yourself, unless you're uncertain what you're doing and why.

Answer (score 4):

Bigger question is: would you drive with a blindfold on? That’s how it is if you develop a system without referential constraints. Keep in mind, that business requirements change, application design changes, respective logical assumptions in the code changes, logic itself can be refactored, and so on. In general, constraints in databases are put in place under contemporary logical assumptions, seemingly correct for particular set of logical assertions and assumptions.

Through the lifecycle of an application, referential and data checks constraints police data collection via the application, especially when new requirements drive logical application changes.

**To the subject of this listing** - a foreign key does not by itself "improve performance", nor does it "degrade performance" significantly from a standpoint of real-time transaction processing system. However, there is an aggregated cost for constraint checking in HIGH volume "batch" system. So, here is the difference, real-time vs. batch transaction process; batch processing - where aggreated cost, incured by constraint checks, of a sequentially processed batch poses a performance hit.

In a well designed system, data consistency checks would be done "before" processing a batch through (nevertheless, there is a cost associated here also); therefore, foreign key constraint checks are not required during load time. In fact all constraints, including foreign key, should be temporarily disabled till the batch is processed.

**QUERY PERFORMANCE** - if tables are joined on foreign keys, be cognizant of the fact that foreign key columns are NOT INDEXED (though the respective primary key is indexed by definition). By indexing a foreign key, for that matter, by indexing any key, and joining tables on indexed helps with better performances, not by joining on non-indexed key with foreign key constraint on it.

**Changing subjects**, if a database is just supporting website display/rendering content/etc and recording clicks, then a database with full constraints on all tables is over kill for such purposes. Think about it. Most websites don’t even use a database for such. For similar requirements, where data is just being recorded and not referenced per say, use an in-memory database, which does not have constraints. This doesn’t mean that there is no data model, yes logical model, but no physical data model.

Comment: Well, I don't know why inserting 3 double newlines in place of blanks and changing two words counts as '67% is Jonathan Leffler', but I don't think I had done anything like that much work on it.  The main text was contributed by @jay (user 183837).

Comment: I just assumed that paragrahps won't work here as is the case in most other sites. So, I put it all as one, using bolds for flow change.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with the previous answers in that they are useful to mantain data consistency. However, there was an [interesting post by Jeff Atwood](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001152.html) some weeks ago that discussed the pros and cons of normalized and consistent data.

In a few words, a denormalized database can be faster when handling huge amounts of data; and you may not care about precise consistency depending on the application, but it forces you to be much more careful when dealing with data, as the DB won't be.

Comment: Jeff makes some good points. However, Dan Chak in "Enterprise Rails" shows a way to design cache tables that are essentially a de-normalized copy of the data. Queries run fast, and if the table doesn't have to be refreshed, it works well. 

I find that if your data drives the behaviour (e.g. application state) of your application, you need data to be normalized as much as possible because otherwise inconsistent data leads to inconsistent application behaviour.

Comment: A denormalised data *warehouse* may be of use when *reading* large volumes of data *on consistent, anticipated access paths*. In all other scenarios, this is a dangerous fallacy.

Answer (score 3):

The Clarify database is an example of a commercial database that has no primary or foreign keys.

http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/18869

The funny thing is, the technical documentation goes to great lengths to explain how tables are related, what columns to use to join them etc.

In other words, they **could** have joined the tables with explicit declarations (DRI) but they **chose not to**.

Consequently, the Clarify database is full of inconsistencies and it underperforms.

But I suppose it made the developers job easier, not having to write code to deal with referential integrity such as checking for related rows before deleting, adding.

And that, I think, is the main benefit of not having foreign key constraints in a relational database.  It makes it easier to develop, at least that is from a devil-may-care point of view.

Comment: The code to handle a failed referential integrity check is a lot smaller than the code to handle inconsistent data.

Comment: @Jay agree!  Don't think I'm advocating this approach.

Answer (score 3):

If you are absolutey sure, that the one underlying database system will not change in the future, I would use foreign keys to ensure data integrity.

**But here is another very good real-life reason not to use foreign keys at all:**

You are developing a product, which should support different database systems.

If you are working with the Entity Framework, which is able to connect to many different database systems, you may also want to support "open-source-free-of-charge" serverless databases. Not all of these databases may support your foreign key rules (updating, deleting rows...).

**This can lead to different problems:**

1.) You may run into errors, when the database structure is created or updated. Maybe there will only be silent errors, because your foreign keys are just ignored by the database system.

2.) If you rely on foreign keys, you will propably make less or even no data integrity checks in your business logic. Now, if the new database system does not support these foreign key rules or just behaves in a different way, you have to rewrite your business logic.

You may ask: Who needs different database systems? Well, not everybody can afford or wants a full blown SQL-Server on his machine. This is software, which needs to be maintained. Others already have invested time and money in some other DB system. Serverless database are great for small customers on only one machine.

Nobody knows, how all of these DB systems behave, but your business logic, with integrity checks, always stays the same.

Answer (score 2):

They can make deleting records more cumbersome - you can't delete the "master" record where there are records in other tables where foreign keys would violate that constraint.  You can use triggers to have cascading deletes.

If you chose your primary key unwisely, then changing that value becomes even more complex.  For example, if I have the PK of my "customers" table as the person's name, and make that key a FK in the "orders" table", if the customer wants to change his name, then it is a royal pain...  but that is just shoddy database design.

I believe the advantages in using fireign keys outweighs any supposed disadvantages.

Comment: I tend to rarely delete things anyhow.  Just mark have a "Visible/active" bit.

Comment: +1 for "I believe the advantages in using fireign keys outweighs any supposed disadvantages"

Comment: You never, ever *change* a primary key's value. You *delete* the whole row and *recreate* it differently. If you think you need to *change* it, your schema is flawed.

Comment: Changing the customer name would not be a pain at all IF your foreign key is set on the CustomerId (PK). in the orders table. The only way it would be a pain is if the FK was set on CustomerName which should never be the case. IMHO

Answer (score 2):

Verifying foreign key constraints takes some CPU time, so some folks omit foreign keys to get some extra performance.

Comment: How much CPU time is spent removing duplicate and inconsistent data?

Comment: Yeah, this is true. On a system I work on we have to insert 10 - 40 gigs of data at a time into a database and FK performance with and without is visible in total time it takes.

Answer (score 2):

Additional Reason to use Foreign Keys:
- Allows greater reuse of a database

Additional Reason to NOT use Foreign Keys:
- You are trying to lock-in a customer into your tool by reducing reuse.

Answer (score 2):

I know only Oracle databases, no other ones, and I can tell that Foreign Keys are essential for maintaining data integrity. Prior to inserting data, a data structure needs to be made, and be made correctlty. When that is done - and thus all primary AND foreign keys are created - the work is done !

Meaning : orphaned rows ? No. Never seen that in my life. Unless a bad programmer forgot the foreign key, or if he implemented that on another level. Both are - in context of Oracle - huge mistakes, which will lead to data duplication, orphan data, and thus : data corruption. I can't imagine a database without FK enforced. It looks like chaos to me. It's a bit like the Unix permission system : imagine that everybody is root. Think of the chaos.

Foreign Keys are essential, just like Primary Keys. It's like saying : what if we removing Primary Keys ? Well, total chaos is going to happen. That's what. You may not move the primary or foreign key responsibility to the programming level, it must be at the data level.

Drawbacks ? Yes, absolutely ! Because on insert, a lot more checks are going to be happening. But, if data integrity is more important than performance, it's a no-brainer. The problem with performance on Oracle is more related to indexes, which come with PK and FK's.

Answer (score 1):

The argument I have heard is that the front-end should have these business rules. Foreign keys "add unnecessary overhead" when you shouldn't be allowing any insertions that break your constraints in the first place. Do I agree with this? No, but that is what I have always heard.

**EDIT:** My guess is he was referring to *foreign key constraints*, not foreign keys as a concept.

Comment: Nope. He doesn't like actual keys!

Comment: That amazes me. There is a big difference between not liking foreign key constraints and not liking foreign keys. I'm not sure how you have a relational database without them.

Comment: Yes I was shocked when I heard him. He might have been unintentionally tongue-in-cheek however; perhaps he will post here and clarify at some stage :-)

Answer (score 1):

To me, if you want to go by the [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) standards, it is critical to have foreign keys to ensure referential integrity.

Answer (score 1):

I have to second most of the comments here, Foreign Keys are necessary items to ensure that you have data with integrity.  The different options for ON DELETE and ON UPDATE will allow you to get around some of the "down falls" that people mention here regarding their use.

I find that in 99% of all my projects I will have FK's to enforce the integrity of the data, however, there are those rare occasions where I have clients that MUST keep their old data, regardless of how bad it is....but then I spend a lot of time writing code that goes in to only get the valid data anyway, so it becomes pointless.

Answer (score 1):

How about maintainability and constancy across application life cycles?  Most data has a longer lifespan than the applications that make use of it.  Relationships and data integrity are much too important to leave to the hope that the next dev team gets it right in the app code.  If you haven't worked on a db with dirty data that doesn't respect the natural relationships, you will.  The importance of data integrity will then become very clear.

Answer (score 1):

I also think that foreign keys are a necessity in most databases.  The only drawback (besides the performance hit that comes with having enforced consistence) is that having a foreign key allows people to write code that assumes there is a functional foreign key.  That should never be allowed.

For example, I've seen people write code that inserts into the referenced table and then attempts inserts into the referencing table without verifying the first insert was successful.  If the foreign key is removed at a later time, that results in an inconsistent database.

You also don't have the option of assuming a specific behavior on update or delete.  You still need to write your code to do what you want regardless of whether there is a foreign key present.  If you assume deletes are cascaded when they are not, your deletes will fail.  If you assume updates to the referenced columns are propogated to the referencing rows when they are not, your updates will fail.  For the purposes of writing code, you might as well not have those features.

If those features are turned on, then your code will emulate them anyway and you'll lose a little performance.

So, the summary....  Foreign keys are essential if you need a consistent database.  Foreign keys should never be assumed to be present or functional in code that you write.

Answer (score 1):

I echo the answer by Dmitriy - very well put.

For those who are worried about the performance overhead FK's often bring, there's a way (in Oracle) you can get the query optimiser advantage of the FK constraint without the cost overhead of constraint validation during insert, delete or update. That is to create the FK constraint with the attributes RELY DISABLE NOVALIDATE. This means the query optimiser ASSUMES that the constraint has been enforced when building queries, without the database actually enforcing the constraint. You have to be very careful here to take the responsibility when you populate a table with an FK constraint like this to make absolutely sure you don't have data in your FK column(s) that violate the constraint, as if you do so you could get unreliable results from queries that involve the table this FK constraint is on.

I usually use this strategy on some tables in my data mart schema, but not in my integrated staging schema. I make sure the tables I am copying data from already have the same constraint enforced, or the ETL routine enforces the constraint.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the people answering here get too hung up on the importance of referential integrity implemented via referential constraints. Working on large databases with referential integrity just does not perform well. Oracle seems particularly bad at cascading deletes. My rule of thumb is that applications should never update the database directly and should be via a stored procedure. This keeps the code base inside the database, and means that the database maintains its integrity.

Where many applications may be accessing the database, problems do arise because of referential integrity constraints but this is down to a control.

There is a wider issue too in that, application developers may have very different requirements that database developers may not necessarily be that familiar with.

Comment: "applications should never update the database directly and should be via a stored procedure. This keeps the code base inside the database, and means that the database maintains its integrity." <- There's an assumption here that logic in stored procedures can't violate data integrity, which is just plain wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I have heard this argument too - from people who forgot to put an index on their foreign keys and then complained that certain operations were slow (because constraint checking could take advantage of any index). So to sum up: There is no good reason not to use foreign keys. All modern databases support cascaded deletes, so...

Comment: I believe that the real reason FKs constraints are not used by some (most, from my perspective) is sheer laziness under the pretense that they can defend their laziness with their performance savings argument.

I firmly believe that the vast majority of the Stupidity Expense our company incurs is due to lack enforcement of FK constraints and the ripple effect that this has through a company.

Lack of Unique Keys is the other thing that drives me nuts next to 2000+ line stored procedures with 12 levels of nested IFs and random indenting, but I'll stop now.

Answer (score 0):

One time when an FK might cause you a problem is when you have historical data that references the key (in a lookup table) even though you no longer want the key available.
Obviously the solution is to design things better up front, but I am thinking of real world situations here where you don't always have control of the full solution.
For example: perhaps you have a look up table `customer_type` that lists different types of customers - lets say you need to remove a certain customer type, but (due to business restraints) aren't able to update the client software, and nobody invisaged this situation when developing the software, the fact that it is a foreign key in some other table may prevent you from removing the row even though you know the historical data that references it is irrelevant.
After being burnt with this a few times you probably lean away from db enforcement of relationships.
(I'm not saying this is good - just giving a reason why you may decide to avoid FKs and db contraints in general)

Comment: If I understand what you are trying to say, I think my answer to that would be to logically delete the record in the lookup table or archive the no longer relevant historical data and archive the lookup record too.

Answer (score 0):

I'll echo what Dmitriy said, but adding on a point.

I worked on a batch billing system that needed to insert large sets of rows on 30+ tables.  We weren't allowed to do a data pump (Oracle) so we had to do bulk inserts.  Those tables had foreign keys on them, but we had already ensured that they were not breaking any relationships.

Before insert, we disable the foreign key constraints so that Oracle doesn't take forever doing the inserts.  After the insert is successful, we re-enable the constraints.

PS: In a large database with many foreign keys and child row data for a single record, sometimes foreign keys can be bad, and you may want to disallow cascading deletes.  For us in the billing system, it would take too long and be too taxing on the database if we did cascading deletes, so we just mark the record as bad with a field on the main driver (parent) table.

Answer (score 0):

Like many things, it's a tradeoff.  It's a question of where you want to do the work to verify the data integrity:

(1) use a foreign key (a single point to configure for a table, feature is already implemented, tested, proven to work)

(2) leave it to the users of the database (possible multiple users/apps updating the same table (s) meaning more potential points of failure and increased complexity in testing).

It's more efficient for the database to do (2), easier to maintain and less risk with (1).

Comment: The efficiency argument is overrated. Rule #1 is data integrity. If performance suffers because of FK constraints, change it. Rarely is that the reason.

Answer (score 0):

One good principle of data structure design is to ensure that every attribute of a table or object be subject to a well-understood constraint. This is important because if you or your program can count on valid data in the database, you are less likely to have program defects caused by bad data. You also spend less time writing code to handle error conditions, and you are more likely to write error-handling code up front.

In many cases these constraints can be defined at compile-time, in which case you can write a filter to ensure that the attribute always falls within range, or the attempt to save the attribute fails.

However, in many cases these constraints can change at run-time. For example, you may have a "cars" table that has "colour" as an attribute which initially takes on the values, say, of "red", "green" and "blue". It is possible during the execution of the program to add valid colours to that initial list, and new "cars" added may take on any colour in the up-to-date list of colours. Furthermore, you usually want this updated list of colours to survive a program restart.

To answer your question, it turns out that if you have a requirement for data constraint that can change at run-time, and those changes must survive a program restart, foreign keys are the simplest and most concise solution to the problem. The development cost is the addition of one table (e.g. "colours", a foreign key constraint to the "cars" table, and an index), and the run-time cost is the extra table lookup for the up-to-date colours to validate the data, and this run-time cost is usually mitigated by indexing and caching.

If you don't use foreign keys for these requirements, you must write software to manage the list, look valid entries, save it to disk, structure the data efficiently if the list is large, ensure that any updates to the list don't corrupt the list file, provide serial access to the list in case there are multiple readers and/or writers, and so on. i.e. You need to implement a lot of RDBMS functionality.

Answer (score 0):

In a project I worked on there was often implicit rather than explicit relationships so that numerous tables could be joined on the same column.

Take the following table

**Address**

- AddressId (PK)
- EntityId
- EntityType
- City
- State
- Country
- Etc..

Possible values of EntityType may be Employee, Company, Customer, and the EntityId refers to the primarky key of whichever table you were interested in.

I don't really think this is the best way to do things, but it worked for this project.

Answer (score 0):

In DB2, if MQTs (Materialized Query Tables) are used, foreign key constraints are required for the optimizer to choose the right plan for any given query. Since they contain the cardinality information, the optimizer uses the metadata heavily to use a MQT or not.

Answer (score 0):

**Q**uite often we receive the errors with **FK constraints**
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
Suppose there are two tables inventory_source and contract_lines, and we are referring *inventory_source_id in contract_lines from inventory_source* and suppose we want to delete record from inventory_source  and the record is already present in contract_lines or we want to delete the PK column from Base table, we get errors for FK constraints, we can avoid it using the steps jotted below.

```
CREATE TABLE inventory_source (
inventory_source_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
display_name varchar(40) NOT NULL,
state_id int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (inventory_source_id),
KEY state_id (state_id),
CONSTRAINT ba_inventory_source_state_fk FOREIGN KEY (state_id) REFERENCES   ba_state (state_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE contract_lines(
contract_line_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
inventory_source_id int(11) NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (contract_line_id),
UNIQUE KEY contract_line_id (contract_line_id),
KEY AI_contract_line_id (contract_line_id),
KEY contract_lines_inventory_source_fk (inventory_source_id),
CONSTRAINT contract_lines_inventory_source_fk FOREIGN KEY       (inventory_source_id) REFERENCES ba_inventory_source (inventory_source_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=135 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;
```

We can overcome it using the following steps:-

1. Delete or update the row from the inventory_source will  automatically delete or update the matching rows in the contract_lines table and this is known as cascade delete or update.
2. Another way of doing it is  setting the column i.e inventory_source_id   in the contract_lines table to NULL, when a record corresponding to it is deleted in the inventory_source table.
3. We can restrict the parent table for delete or update in other words one can reject the delete or update operation for the inventory_source table.
4. Attempt to delete or update a primary key value will not be permitted to proceed if there is a related foreign key value in the referenced table.

Answer (score -1):

I always thought it was lazy not to use them. I was taught it should always be done. But then, I didnt listen to Joel's discussion. He may have had a good reason, I don't know.

Comment: It was more of an off-the-cuff remark than a discussion, though perhaps I should research precisely what he thinks on the subject independently! However I was curious about the community's opinion on this topic as well!

Answer (score -1):

Wowowo...
Answers everywhere. Actually this is the most complicated topic I have ever encountered.
I use FKs when they are needed but on production environment I rarely use them. 
Here is my whys I rarely use the Fks:
 1. Most of the time I am dealing with huge data on small server to improve performance I need to remove the FKs. Because when you have FKs and you do Create, Update or Delete the RDBMS first check if there no constraint violation and if you have huge DB that could be something fatal
 2. Sometimes I need to import data from others places and because I am not too sure of how well structured they are, I simply drop the FKs.
 3. In case you are dealing with multiple DBs and having reference key in an other DB will not go well(as for now) until you remove the FKs (cross database relations)
 4. They was also a case when you write an application which will seat on whatever RDBMS or you want your DB to be exported and imported in any RDBMS system in this case each specific RDBMS system has his own way of dealing with FKs and you will probably be obliged to drop the use of FKs.
 5. If you user RDBMS platform (ORMs) you know that some of them offer their own mapping depending on the solution and technicality their offer and you don't care about creating the tables and their FKs.
 6. Before the last point will be knowledge to deal with DB that has FKs and the knowledge to write an application that does all the Job without the need of FK
 7. Lastly as I started saying it all depend on your scenario, in case knowledge is not a barrier. You will always want to run the best of the best you can get!

Thank you everybody!

Answer (score -9):

I can see a few reasons to use foreign keys (Orphaned rows, as someone mentioned, are annoying) but I never use them either. With a relatively sane DB schema, I don't think they are 100% needed. Constraints are good, but enforcing them via software is a better method, I think.

Alex

Comment: Enforcing foreign keys via software isn't easy because of multi concurrency issues. What if user A deletes the parent while user B is inserting children?

Comment: What if I update the data manually? What if there's a bug in the code? You stated your opinion, but you didn't even attempt to back it up. -1