# What will these foreign keys do?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I used an online SQL builder to help design some MySQL tables I'm working on.  Foreign keys always confuse me.

The code I came up with tries to add these 4 foreign keys but I want to make sure that I want them before I add them.

```
ALTER TABLE `users` ADD FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES `settings` (`user_id`);
ALTER TABLE `logins` ADD FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`);
ALTER TABLE `mail_threads` ADD FOREIGN KEY (folder_id) REFERENCES `mail_folders` (`folder_id`);
ALTER TABLE `mail_message` ADD FOREIGN KEY (thread_id) REFERENCES `mail_threads` (`thread_id`);
```

So basically what will to limit me from doing?  All 4 of these tables below, I need to be able to update individually without them messing with the other, so should I not use a foreign key on them?

Comment: Foreign Keys are not optional. They are part of your domain relationships.

Comment: Note that, if you use MyISAM as the table type, foreign key declarations are currently ignored. You currently need InnoDB for foreign key constraints to be honored (foreign key support for MyISAM should be in the works, however).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Foreign Keys are a way for the database to assign an association to a 'parent' table.

I'll start from the bottom of your list and work my way up.

The bottom FK states that the column `mail_message.thread_id` is a reference to `mail_threads.thread_id`
The next FK states that the column `mail_threads.folder_id` is a reference to `mail_folders.folder_id`

What this means is that a mail_thread "belongs to" a mail_folder, and a mail_message "belongs to" a mail_thread.  So if you have no mail_thread with a thread_id of 20 you can not create a mail_message with a thread_id of 20, because it wouldn't make any sense (and the reference wouldn't function).  It also prevents you from deleting a mail_thread of say thread_id 20 if there are messages within that thread without either cascading the delete (forcing the deletion of everything associated through the constraints) or deleting the messages first.

In a nutshell, those two constraints say:
mail_messages belong to mail_threads which belong to mail_folders
-or-
mail_folders have zero to many mail_threads which have zero to many mail_messages

SO Question with the benefits/pitfalls of FKs:
[What's wrong with foreign keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83147/whats-wrong-with-foreign-keys)

Answer (score 1):

Foreign key will guarantee that you will not make a reference to a record that does not exist. The constraints created by foreign keys are often considered fundamental to enforce data integrity in a database.

In fact I think your first foreign key may need to be tweaked as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE `settings` ADD FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`);
```

This will guarantee that any `user_id` in the table `settings` will be a valid `user_id` already present in the `users` table. In addition, it will not allow you to delete a row in the `users` table if there is still a row in the `settings` table that references the user that is going to deleted. Thus it will also make sure there will be no orphan rows.

Your original foreign key would have required the settings row to be inserted before the users row, which I believe is not your intent. That foreign key is checking for a `user_id` in the `settings` table before allowing a new user in the `users` table.

As for the following foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE `logins` ADD FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES `users` (`user_id`);
```

This will also guarantee that any `user_id` in the table `logins` will be a valid `user_id` already present in the `users` table. The database will not allow you to have a record with `user_id = 100` in table `logins` if there is not a user with `user_id = 100` in the table `users`.

You can apply the same logic to the `mail_threads` constraint, which requires a `folder_id` already present int the `mail_folders` table, and the same for the `mail_message` constraint which requires a valid `thread_id`.

Comment: If the foreign key's goal is to ensure that settings rows are never abandoned, that should be changed. However, it seems more likely that the code seeks to ensure that no user is ever without a settings row, in which case the existing code makes sense.

Comment: Wouldn't that require the `settings` row to be inserted before the `users` row? That foreign key is checking for a `user_id` in the `settings` table before allowing a new user in the `users` table.

Answer (score 0):

Foreign keys simply keep object integrity in place. This code will not let you change a user's ID if there is no row in `settings` with the same user ID. It will not let you change a user ID in the `logins` table if there is no corresponding user. Etc.

What do you mean by "messing with" the tables? You are free to update the `users` table at any time without updating the `settings` table, as long as every user always has a corresponding settings row. Otherwise, the query will fail.

You should leave the code in unless you have an excellent reason to remove it. If the foreign key constraints ever get in your way, it is simply a notice that your code is doing something wrong.