# Mysql error Cannot add foreign key constraint when i add foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, database

IN my mysql database i have two table review and products

```
mysql> desc review;
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| review        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| rating        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| created_at    | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| updated_at    | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
| reviewer_name | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
| product_id    | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+

mysql> desc products;
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name    | varchar(255)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| details | text             | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

When i try to make product_id in review table as foreign key that refer to id in products table i found this error and the query what i gave was:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE review ADD FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products(id);
ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Please help me out what the problem is and how can i figure it out

Comment: Probably due to datatype precision mismatch between int 10 and int 11

Comment: So what i want to do now

Comment: Yes i changed and it working correctly...Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be two reasons for the error.

**The datatype precision is different for two columns i.e.**

```
products -> id | int(10) unsigned  // here int(10)
product_id     | int(11)           // here int(11)
```

make the precision same by altering the table structure

**To create foreign key relation ship the parent table column must be
unique or a primary column.**

So check if `products(id)` is primary or unique, if not make it primary or unique.

Comment: I need another help when i try to insert values inside review table `mysql> insert into review(review,rating,reviewer_name,product_id) values ('Products are good','4','John Deo','1');
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`birdys_dev`.`review`, CONSTRAINT `review_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`) REFERENCES `products` (`id`))
`

Comment: Could you please help me

Comment: With foreign key relationship, you can only insert those values in child table which are already present in parent table for the foreign key binding columns

Answer (score 2):

The "precision" of the int types means nothing. It's just a hint for display width. It makes no difference to the size of the data type.

What caused your error was that your `products.id` was `int unsigned`, but you were trying to declare a foreign key for `review.product_id` which was `int` (signed).

The difference between signed and unsigned int was what makes the data types incompatible for referential integrity. You could make one `int(10) unsigned` and the other `int(327) unsigned` and it would be okay.

Answer (score 0):

alter your table structure

> id | int(11)

or set

> product_id | int(10) unsigned

do which way is batter for you. also you can also get better understanding about FOREIGN KEY from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/83147/whats-wrong-with-foreign-keys)